# Can I use regression analysis for this type of research

Tags: regression, multiple-regression

Can I use regression analysis when determining the impact of organizational change to job satisfaction and organizational commitment? my IV is organizational change and DV are job satisfaction and organizational commitment. I will use likert scale for my IV and DV

Answer (score 0):

A simple linear regression model may not be appropriate because you have a dependent variable on a Likert scale.

If you have enough observations in your data, you could go for an Ordinal Logit Model. It would allow you to further estimate the marginal effects of the independent variable on the dependent variable. You can also predict the probabilities of each outcome of your Likert scale.

However, it won't give any reliable results if your dataset is too small.